# How define a fallback key with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I'm using `pgfkeys` to define some key-value options. I need some default value to initialize a key and I also want to use this default value as a fallback indepentent from the passed key value pair.

What I've tried is to create somekind of a child key. But I don't know how to use this to initialize the actual key with it.

In the MWE at the **workaround** I would like to use the original initialized value for **titlepage**. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.def}
    Test file content
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    test/.cd,
    titlepage/.store in = \@file@titlepage,
    titlepage/.default = \jobname.def,%<-- Set default value
    titlepage = \jobname.def, % <-- initial titlepage
}
\newcommand{\testtitlepage}{%
    \InputIfFileExists{\@file@titlepage}
    {Found titlepage: \@file@titlepage\par} % <-- only for testing}
    {Workaround: \pgfkeysvalueof{test/titlepage}}%<-- Try to use default value of titlepage
}
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{test/titlepage = test.def}% <-- Set non-existing file to activate workaround
    \testtitlepage
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I updated my MWE to use `.default`. But I'm still unable to use this default key inside \testtitlepage, when the passed file don't exist.

Comment: Isn't this what the `pgfkeys` modifiers `.default` or `.initial` are meant for?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated my question using the `.default` modifier. But I still don't know how to get this default value inside my macro testtitlepage, when the passed file don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this here:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.def}
    Test file content
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
    test/.cd,
    titlepage/.store in = \@file@titlepage,
    titlepage/.default = \jobname.def,%<-- Set default value
    titlepage = \jobname.def, % <-- initial titlepage
}

\newcommand{\testtitlepage}{%
    \InputIfFileExists{\@file@titlepage}
    {Found titlepage: \@file@titlepage\par} % <-- only for testing}
    {Workaround: \pgfkeysvalueof{/test/titlepage/.@def}}%<-- Try to use default value of titlepage
}
\begin{document}
    \testtitlepage

    \pgfkeys{/test/titlepage = notexisting.def}% <-- Set non-existing file to activate workaround
    \testtitlepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is working nicely. Do the subkey `.@def` hold the value of the `.default` modifier? I couldn't find something within the pgf manual.